# How must define my own cmake function

Tags: cmake

I using cmake 2.8.8.
And I want to make function that get list of source files check if they exist and put exist files in another variable that i must use in my CMakeList.txt.Here is my function

```
function(SetSources SourceList Sourceses )

message(STATUS "Sourcelist " ${SourceList})

foreach(SRC ${SourceList})

FILE(GLOB Sourceses ${SRC})

message(STATUS "Sources " ${Sourceses})

endforeach(SRC)

endfunction(SetSources)
```

Here is what i call my function and which argument i push to it

```
set(SourceList plugincustomresourcemgr.cpp PluginCustomResourceDLL.cppextendedarchive.cpp)

set(Sourceses)

SetSources(SourceList Sourceses)
```

Output form

```
message(STATUS "Sourcelist " ${SourceList})
```

is

```
--SourceList SourceList
```

This is not pass value. What I'm doing wrong and how i must handle function arguments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that function in cmake is with fixed number of arguments (like c/c++)
When i define variable I must pass his value with ${} to function.If variable have more then one value and function get only one argument, function will get last value.If i don't pass variable by reference(${}) function will get name of variable like value.

To solve my problem i defined macro that not get arguments

```
macro(checkSources)

foreach(SRC ${SourceList})

file(GLOB Sources ${SRC})

endforeach(SRC)

endmacro(checkSources)
```

This work fine if variables "SourceList" and "Sources" are define in current CMakeList.txt
I know, is more good idea to check sources with

```
file(GLOB Sources ${SourceList})
```

But this is example with which i test cmake.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is to use ARGV and ARGC to cooperate with each other. Their meanings are like argv and argc of main in C/C++, representing the number of parameters and parameters respectively.
eg:

```
function(showSrcList srcList)
message("ARGC = "${ARGC})
message("ARGV = "${ARGV})

set(i 0)
while(i LESS ${ARGC})
    message("ARG = "${ARGV${i}}) #ARGV0、ARGV1...
    math(EXPR i "${i} + 1")
endwhile()
endfunction()
showSrcList (a.c b.c c.c d.c)

==== output ====
ARGC = 4
ARGV = a.c b.c c.c d.c
ARG = a.c
ARG = b.c
ARG = c.c
ARG = d.c
```